# How do you say ‘vegetable oil’ in Esperanto?

Tags: terminology

My guess is ‘vegetala oleo’ (or, ‘vegetoleo’ for short).

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia suggests [*legoma oleo*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legoma_oleo). I find this term strange though, because vegetable oil can also be oil from plant-like things that are not vegetables (like nuts or seeds). The English term is also used for this oddly enough.¹ Several other languages use a word relating to plants or vegetation in general rather than vegetables specifically. Considering all sources of the page are in English, I presume an English speaker chose the term.

I'd suggest *vegetaĵa oleo*, considering both [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#oleo) and [ReVo](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/ole.html#ole.0o) use *vegetaĵa origino* in their definition. This way it also encapsulates nuts, seeds, fruits etc., rather than just vegetables.

---

1) From the Oxford dictionary:
vegetable oil
noun
an oil derived from plants, e.g., canola oil, olive oil, sunflower oil.

Comment: `vegetaĵa oleo/planta oleo`